# Set a multi-term filter using "AND" method

Tags: jquery, algorithm, filtering

I would like to set a jQuery multi-term filter, **using `AND` method.**
For example, searching for `foo bar`, or `foo+bar` will return items with **both** `foo` and `bar` strings in their value, but not those with only `foo` or `bar`.

Right now, I use this code:

```js
$('#filter').keyup(function(ev) {
    $('div').show();
    if($(this).val() != '') {
        var terms = $(this).val().toLowerCase().split(/[\s+]+/); 
        $('div').hide()
        for (var i = 0, n = terms.length; i < n; i++) {
            $('div[data-search*="'+terms[i]+'"]').show();
        };
    }
});

// "nihil"       returns 2 results
// "nulla"       returns 1 result
// "nihil nulla" returns 3 results
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter">

<div data-search="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel mollitia recusandae porro quidem optio expedita veritatis aliquid debitis explicabo incidunt odit beatae laboriosam rem amet quis corporis assumenda rerum ab!">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel mollitia recusandae porro quidem optio expedita veritatis aliquid debitis explicabo incidunt odit beatae laboriosam rem amet quis corporis assumenda rerum ab!</div>
<div data-search="Eligendi quasi maxime accusantium vel alias nihil dolorum enim maiores aspernatur ab cumque iusto exercitationem dicta deleniti qui ipsa perferendis doloremque non quod itaque earum at sunt. A consequatur in.">Eligendi quasi maxime accusantium vel alias nihil dolorum enim maiores aspernatur ab cumque iusto exercitationem dicta deleniti qui ipsa perferendis doloremque non quod itaque earum at sunt. A consequatur in.</div>
<div data-search="Rerum ratione temporibus nulla dolorem cum minus dolores eius quia natus pariatur. Non nisi sunt iusto officiis ipsa adipisci illo enim ratione repudiandae sint iure repellat tempore est ea omnis.">Rerum ratione temporibus nulla dolorem cum minus dolores eius quia natus pariatur. Non nisi sunt iusto officiis ipsa adipisci illo enim ratione repudiandae sint iure repellat tempore est ea omnis.</div>
<div data-search="Quos nihil alias ipsam voluptates eius itaque tempora sapiente natus odio nobis possimus voluptate! Aspernatur ea molestiae dolor voluptatem beatae vel rerum adipisci minima maiores at a alias maxime eos.">Quos nihil alias ipsam voluptates eius itaque tempora sapiente natus odio nobis possimus voluptate! Aspernatur ea molestiae dolor voluptatem beatae vel rerum adipisci minima maiores at a alias maxime eos.</div>
<div data-search="Incidunt nobis harum quasi voluptas sed quo qui repellendus tempore architecto. Maxime aliquid officia similique culpa molestiae nobis incidunt praesentium ducimus sunt necessitatibus veritatis iusto quis esse vitae hic perferendis.">Incidunt nobis harum quasi voluptas sed quo qui repellendus tempore architecto. Maxime aliquid officia similique culpa molestiae nobis incidunt praesentium ducimus sunt necessitatibus veritatis iusto quis esse vitae hic perferendis.</div>
```

You can clearly see this is working with `OR` method, then searching for `foo bar` will also return results with only `foo` or `bar`. How can I change this `OR` method into a `AND` one ?

Please note my main problem is that the terms can be in an other order than the search field's one.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could concatenate a string selector: http://jsfiddle.net/aUcPf/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff Nice way... Take the time to post it as an answer and I'll set this thread as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Raphaël Althaus posted a more elegant answer which he has deleted using filter(). I see still a problem in both ways (Raphaël's answer and mine) when searching for first word which is capitalized. You can see Raphaël's answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/aUcPf/4/

Comment: The capital isn't a problem, I'll only use lowercase strings for `data-search` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate a string as selector:

```
$('#filter').keyup(function(ev) {
    $('div').show();
    if($(this).val() != '') {
        var terms = $(this).val().toLowerCase().split(/[\s+]+/); 
        $('div').hide()
        var selector = "div";
        for (var i = 0, n = terms.length; i < n; i++) {
            selector += '[data-search*="'+terms[i]+'"]';
        };
        $(selector).show();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aUcPf/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I take care of Raphaël's answer, the use of `filter` is interesting, but a bit more greedy, I guess.